# Prevent images in rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am working on a C# winForms application where I am using lots of RichTextBoxes. I found out that if I copied an image and pasted that in any RichTextBox, the image would be posted. Is there a way not to allow images to be pasted in the RichTextBox. In other words, to only allow keyboard characters.

Comment: I reckon the best you can do is recognize that the content of the RichTextBox has changed and then perform some manipulation on the RTF content to remove any images that may have been pasted in.

Comment: how could i know that there is an image ?

Comment: The RTF format defines 'tags' - you'd need to parse the RTF using some means (perhaps a regular expression) and remove tags relating to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to answer my question. Here it is in case someone else was looking for it.

```
private void InputExpressionRchTxt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bool ctrlV = e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V;
    bool shiftIns = e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert;
    if (ctrlV || shiftIns)
        if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: ContainsImage works only with bipmap format

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the answer above is that it doesn't work in cases where there is mixed content.  For example if you highlight a few rows from a spreadsheet and paste into a richtextbox you end up with more than just the raw text.  I think the better solution is below:

```
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            if (Clipboard.GetData("Text") != null)
                Clipboard.SetText((string)Clipboard.GetData("Text"), TextDataFormat.Text);
            else
                e.Handled = true;
        }            
    }
```

EDIT: The method below was shared by MrCC and is a more direct / better approach than my method above.

```
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
                richTextBox1.Paste(DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Text));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Agreed. Copying text from Onenote for example fills the clipboard with text  and a bitmap image representing that text. CTRL-V for some reason always inserted the bitmap representation, so intercepting CTRL-V is necessary. The code above is a little roundabout - it overwrites the clipboard with the pure text format if there is one, and lets the internal handler actually do the pasting (hence no `e.Handled=true;` in the if branch). More direct would be: `if (Clipboard.ContainsText()) richTextBox1.Paste(DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Text));` and setting `e.Handled=true;` for either branch.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Your method is better.  Admittedly when I posted my solution I suspected that it could be done without replacing the clipboard, but I couldn't figure out exactly how.  Thanks for sharing your method.  I've edited my answer above to include yours.

Comment: This seems like it would work only work with a QWERTY keyboard. If you had a mouse & a context menu or a different keyboard, how would this work? Is there no higher level or more abstract way to detect a paste?

Comment: I'm def not an expert on the subject, but as far as I am aware the RichTextBox control doesn't support pasting with a mouse and right-click context menu.  The only built-in option is pasting with CTRL-V.  If you had a different control that supported pasting from a context menu then I think in that case you would have to override that particular event handler.

Comment: You should change the `if` line with `if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V || e.Shift & e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can catch paste event and check what object copied to RichTextBox.
If it Image, just delete it.

Comment: how to check if it is an image ?!

Comment: Debug, and see what comes up :)

Comment: Just do : if(copiedObject.GetType() is Image) 
if is true - destroy it or maybe call clear function of textbox

Comment: try this:
        void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RichTextBox txt = sender as RichTextBox;
            if (txt.UndoActionName == "Paste" && txt.Text==" ")
            {
                txt.Clear();
            }
        }

But, one thing: if in ReachTextBox already was some text - it do not work.